# Regex/shell parameters expensions when using cp.spawnSync

Tags: node.js, jq, child-process

I'm testing in the command line a jq command:

```
jq -f config/jest.jq -s reports/jest/*.json
```

Which outputs the content of 3 json files located under `/reports/jest/`, accordings to the filters I've specified under `/config/jest.jq`.

If I try to run the same thing within a node script like so however:

```
  const jq = await cp.spawnSync('jq', ['-f', configPath, '-s', folderPath]);
```

It fails - jq.stderr tells me he can't finds "`/reports/jest/*.json`". If I do this however:

```
  const jq = await cp.spawnSync('jq', ['-f', configPath, '-s', 'reports/jest/app.json', 'reports/jest/backend.json', ]);
```

Then it properly pipes both files into jq. Why is my regular expression working in the command line, but not under spawnSync? How do I need to adapt it so it reads all my json file & parse it as a single large input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a regular expression, but a shell glob (or shell wildcard pattern). It is evaluated by your shell (sh, bash, zsh, …). `spawnSync` is not running a shell, but executing the binary directly, passing all arguments verbatim.

If you need a shell's behavior, you must execute a shell or resolve the wildcard somehow else. Here's a version which uses a shell:

```
const jq = await cp.spawnSync(
  'sh',
  [
    '-c',
    'jq -f ' + configPath + ' -s ' folderPath
  ]);
```

Or

```
const jq = await cp.spawnSync(
  'sh',
  [
    '-c',
    ['jq -f', configPath, '-s', folderPath].join(' ')
  ]);
```

Comment: You really pointed me out to the root cause of the issue here.  Which lead to me re-check the child_process docs. Which led me to to the option {"shell":true}, which if passed forces the command to be run in a shell. Then the glob works as-is. Regardless - very useful answer, wouldn't havbe figured that out without it. THanks.